# jquery image effect not working

Tags: jquery, effects

Here is my code. The initial fadeTo works, nothing else works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" />

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#ButtonBGanim').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
        $('#ButtonBGanim').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeto('fast',1.0)


        }).mouseleave(function(){
        $this.fadeto('fast', 0.1);
        });
    });


</script>

<DIV id="ButtonBGanim">                    </DIV>
```

Comment: Are the lowercase 't's in `fadeto` a typo?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `fadeTo` instead of `fadeto` inside both callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

Should be `fadeTo`, not `fadeto`.

Should be `$(this)`, not `$this`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ButtonBGanim').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
    $('#ButtonBGanim').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',1.0);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.1);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: yeah I just noticed that... but the fixed code still doesn't run?

Comment: Yeah, I put up a test page on my localhost to verify it worked before I posted. 

Thanks jitter for adding the closing script tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you may have misspelled fadeTo() but you can also try hover like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" />

$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#ButtonBGanim').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
        $('#ButtonBGanim').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',1.0)


        },function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.1);
        });
    });


</script>
```